# Creating a REST API for static hosting

Tags: json, api, rest, server-side

I know this sounds crazy, but I had a thought and I was willing to try it out. I use GitLab pages for all my online projects, but a lot of them are ASP.NET MVC, which is an issue as I don't think you can run ASP.NET MVC sites on GitLab pages. I then thought, what if I make a site using something like angular or node.js, and have a central API for all my web projects? I thought that was a great idea, until I realized I couldn't use a database either. I guess what I'm asking is, would it be possible to create a REST API that uses JSON files for storage and node.js as the request pages, to create an API without a database?

Comment: You can't execute code on GitLab pages, so no, you can't. They say "Can I use .php pages and connect databases with my sites?
No. GitLab Pages hosts static websites only (HTML, CSS and JS)." https://about.gitlab.com/2016/04/07/gitlab-pages-setup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.

If you think about a database from the perspective of your application code, it is basically just a place to store and retrieve data.

Imagine the database library you are using has two simple methods, `store` and `retrieve`. In your application code, you could write `db.store('here is the item')` and the later on, `db.retrieve()`.

However, those `store` and `retrieve` methods could be implemented in many different ways to provide the same effective behavior from the perspective of your application. Some examples:

- Send/query the data to/from an external data store, such as PostgreSQL
- Write it to a file on disk and read it back later
- Store the data in memory
- Make HTTP requests to an external system to store the data

Some of these options will be more or less appropriate depending on your exact requirements, however, the general idea is that given a database API, you could implement the exact same method signatures with a completely different approach.